# Type of keys of a generic type with a given type

Tags: typescript

That's sound weird, so an exemple will defined the problem better:

Having a `Model`, I wan't the keys `K` where `Model[K]` is a given type `GivenType` (non generic).

So I guess a good start would be `<Model, K extends keyof Model>`, but this doesn't enforce `Model[K]` to be of type `GivenType`.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K;
}[keyof T];

interface Part {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  subparts: Part[];
  updatePart(newName: string): void;
}

type T41 = NonFunctionPropertyNames<Part>; // "id" | "name" | "subparts"
```

So, in our case:

```
type ModelProperty<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Model ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
```